# Dagger2 - define/update value of object at runtime

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

**The Background:**

I'm using `Dagger2` for dependency injection in my `Android` app and I want to inject an object as a singleton into my BaseActivity to be available throughout the whole app, but the value of the Object can only be set after an authentication process and its value depends on the outcome of the authentication.

**The Build:**

This is what my current setup looks like:

```
public interface Tool {
 ...
}

public class ToolOne implements Tool {
 ...
}

public class ToolTwo implements Tool {
 ...
}
```

A general interface and two different implementations of it.

```
public class ToolConfig {

 private Tool currentTool;

 public ToolConfig(Tool tool) {
   this.currentTool = tool;
 }
 ...
}
```

A class that functions as configuration and is used throughout the whole app.

```
@Provides
@PerApplication
ToolConfig provideToolConfig(Tool tool) {
        return new ToolConfig(tool);
}
```

The way the configuration is defined in my ToolModule for Dagger. This will be injected into the BaseActivity to be available for all classes.

**The task:**

How can I set the value of `currentTool` for the configuration? Depending on the authentication process, either `ToolOne` or `ToolTwo` should be set as value of `currentTool`. It should be possible to change it if the authentication process is done again. This will rarely be the case after it was set once, but it could happen and I want to be sure to always use the same instance of the object.

Is there a recommended way how I could do this with Dagger2?

Comment: I doubt you can do that. Afaik Dagger2 works at compile time

Comment: I know, but it seems strange to find a workaround without dagger to use dependency injection in this case, I hope there is a way.

Comment: use a different injector. Dagger2 is only a piece of the puzzle. Dagger2 is not  dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just define a `@Provides` method that redirects between them:

```
@Provides Tool provideTool(
    AuthenticationController authController,
    Provider<ToolOne> toolOneProvider,
    Provider<ToolTwo> toolTwoProvider) {
  if (authController.useToolTwo()) {
    return toolTwoProvider.get();
  }
  return toolOneProvider.get();
}
```

However, in a case like that, you'll need to be very careful to only inject a `Provider<Tool>` (which will check AuthController every time you call `get`) and not `Tool` (which will check AuthController once when the `Tool`-injected class is created but will not auto-update). For this reason it may make sense to create a custom one-method ToolProvider, where you inject the three deps as needed in the @Provides method and return the current tool as a `getCurrentTool` call (etc).